# Create variable from a selected dropbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create a variable from what has been selected from a drop box. I've got it to display what has been selected but would like it to be stored in a variable so that i can do a further mysql query on it. Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
 $sql="select perf_id, perf_datetime, perf_site, perf_responsetime from responsetimes where perf_responsetime > 10.00  and perf_responsetime < 25.00 and perf_datetime >= now() - INTERVAL 5 DAY group by perf_responsetime HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ORDER BY perf_site ASC;";


?>
<form action="action.php">

<select id="mySelect">
<?php
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
if($row[perf_id]==10){

echo "<option value=$row[perf_site] selected>$row[perf_site]</option>";

}else{

echo "<option value=$row[perf_site]>$row[perf_site]</option>";

}

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</form>

<script>

function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;


}

</script>
```

This outputs the dropbox and submit button but would like to it to store selected in variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is an onchange event for option selection that you can use.

For code sample you can use this [on change sample code](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange)